# Как получить среднее значение из массива объектов?

Tags: javascript

Нужно получить среднее значение из ключа `arr.price`

Функцию хочу оставить универсальную, можно например передавать вторым параметром имя ключа по которому будет идти вычисление

```js
function averageNum(arr) {
  return arr.reduce((sum, a) => sum + a, 0) / arr.length;
}

let arr = [
 {title: 'Заголовок', price: '1256.0002'},
 {title: 'Заголовок2', price: '96.07'},
 {title: 'Заголовок3', price: '192.0857'},
 {title: 'Заголовок4', price: '0.000000857'},
];
let arrTest = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7];

console.log(averageNum(arr));
console.log(averageNum(arrTest));
```

Comment: а в чём сложность заключается?

Comment: @Алексей в reduce не могу передать объект, здесь нужен какой то другой вариант

Comment: Прийдётся передавать не имя параметра, а лямбду геттер

Comment: @eri можно и без лямбд.......а можно и с ними)

Comment: @Meru382 почему не можете передать? Что это значит "не могу передать" ?

Comment: @Алексей работает, спасибо, у меня что то не выходило

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если ключ не передан, считаем по старому, в ином случае берём данные из объекта по ключу (собственно, как и написано в самой задаче дословно):

```js
function averageNum(arr, keyName) {
  return arr.reduce((sum, a) => sum + (keyName === undefined ? a : +a[keyName]), 0) / arr.length;
}

let arr = [
 {title: 'Заголовок', price: '1256.0002'},
 {title: 'Заголовок2', price: '96.07'},
 {title: 'Заголовок3', price: '192.0857'},
 {title: 'Заголовок4', price: '0.000000857'},
];
let arrTest = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7];

console.log(averageNum(arr, 'price'));
console.log(averageNum(arrTest));
```